# How can I search the database using textBox Entry?

Tags: python, sql, database, python-3.x, sqlite

How can I search the database using textBox Entry?

I have some code that shows the correct result if I give a full name, but I want to when I type one letter to show me all the results that hold that letter.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

def printRecords():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('baza.db')
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("select *  from Zaposleni where  Ime LIKE  ?", (z.get(),))
    connection.commit()
    variablename = cur.fetchall()
    print (variablename)

root = Tk()
root.title ( "Search a Book")

z= StringVar()

#Label
Label(root, text = "Enter the name of the book :      ").grid()
#Textbox
bookSearchEntry = Entry(root, textvariable = z)
bookSearchEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
#Button
bookSearchButton = Button(root, text = "Search", command = printRecords)
bookSearchButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would advice you to **not** do something like you have in the code above, because you are introducing to your code potencial security risks ( Go read up on **SQL injection** ).

Comment: @Floaterz: what's the security risk? You can't do sql injection with this code. They are using sqlite properly here.

Comment: Are you asking for how to do the query each time the  user enters a character?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  Yes, or load data to list and use flter if possible. Can also be PqT5 example if you have one? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. This is a solution:

```
 cur.execute("select *  from Zaposleni where  Ime LIKE '%" + z.get() + "%'")
```